# Un-mapping commands in Vim

Tags: vim

So I was looking for a way of indenting multiple lines in vim and someone suggested doing

```
:map <Tab> <
```

and all it does is insert the `<` character whenever I press tab (How did I not see it happen). I tried to do `:map <Tab> <Tab>` and `:map <Tab> \t` to bring back regular indenting, with no success. I am new to `vim` key mapping so I would really appreciate help. Also if someone could point out how to indent multiple lines in `vim`, that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `:unmap` http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)  Google is your friend.

Comment: @AdamLiss but this is the first result in Google now :o

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`:unmap <Tab>` to get the default behavior back.

use `:x>>` to indent x number of lines (from where the cursor is)

Comment: :unmap <Tab> doesn't do the trick.. for some reason :/

Comment: this works for me.

Comment: @Grigor In your question you claimed that you used `map <Tab> <`. To undo this correct command is indeed `unmap <Tab>`, but the next text (“all it does is insert the `<` character”) means that original claim is *false*. There is no way you could insert `<` with such mapping, but it would be true if you have written `imap <Tab> <`. *This* command is undone using `iunmap <Tab>` (note the `i` in both commands). To get correct answers you must be precise.

Comment: A note in case someone had the same struggle as me, if the original mapping is buffer local, then the unmapping must be also: `iunmap <buffer> <Tab>`

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue to revert back tabbing.

`:imap <Tab> <C-t>`
`:imap <S-Tab> <C-d>`

Pressing `Tab` indents the code, `Shift-Tab` reverts indentation the code.

Comment: you can also use `:iunmap <Tab>`. If `<Tab>` is mapped by `:imap`, you have to use `:iunmap` to unmap it. `:unmap <Tab>` doesn't work in this case.